# Ansible playbook with vault file

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

I'm attempting to run a playbook using a vault file, [according to the docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_vault.html) by using the `--vault-password-file` option.

Here is my command:

```
sudo -u ubuntu -H sh -c "cd ~/overseer; ansible-playbook generate_keys.yml -l mgmt --vault-password-file ~/.vaultpw"
```

When running that, I get this output:

```
ERROR: problem running / h o m e / u b u n t u / . v a u l t p w ([Errno 8] Exec format error)
```

I've tried using `/home/ubuntu/.vaultpw` to no avail.

Also according to the docs, I have proper permissions on the file to read.

How can I fix this?  It's not reading my vault password file correctly, it looks like it is interpreting each character as another argument

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out that Ansible thought `.vaultpw` was a script because its permissions were

```
-rwx------
```

I created the file with mode `0600`

```
-rw-------
```

And it worked great.